# If DIV contains checked checkbox set display to block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu consisting of sort criteria. The options per criteria are listed as check boxes in a div wioth class '.collapse_box'.

I need to check each of these div's to see if any of the checkboxes it contains are checked. If there are any checkedboxes I need to set the DIV display to block.

I was thinking along these lines:

```
$('.collapse_box')each(function()

    if( $(this).(input:checked).length() > 0{  //here lies my problem
        $(this).show();
    }

});
```

Seeing that I am very new to javascript and jquery I don't know how to return the checked boxes for $(this). Or better said: the correct method to check if any checkboxes in $(this) are checked.

Comment: At the very least, you're currently missing a `.` and a `{`.

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is wrong, element are always given as string or object:

```
if( $(this).find('input:checked').length > 0){
```

Also, `length` isnt a function, but a property. And you forgot the `.find()`
 [Made you a jsFiddle with demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FUPwP/)

Comment: you need to close the if statement condition with a ")"

Comment: Nice jsfiddle example +1

Answer (score 1):

Alright, assuming that the `input`s are children, something like this will work:

```
$('.collapse_box').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('input').prop('checked')){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

The `.prop('checked')` piece returns a boolean value of whether the `input` is checked or not.

**EDIT** Martijn makes a good point, you can switch it to vanilla JS with a mod to the selector.

```
$('.collapse_box').find('input').each(function(){
    var self = this;
    if(self.checked){
        self.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Comment: If you do the `each()`, it'd be better to do `if( this.checked )`, much more lighhtweight :) Might need to change the loop a bit, just just to highlight an improvement

Comment: haha, saving `this` to `self` isnt needed either in this example. `this` allready is a selector to the element, copying it to another var is just a waste of memory. But +1 for added the style in native JS. jQuery is being overused by allot of the users

Comment: yeah, i know the `self` thing isnt necessary, its just old habits. when referencing `this` more than once, i always capture, just like i do objects. no reason other than personal style.